# htacces file will not give second query variable

Tags: .htaccess

file works for `index.php?p=$1` but not for `index.php?places=$1`

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?p=$1

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?p=$1

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?places=$1

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?places=$1
```

**Update from Comment**

here a part of my `index.php`

```
if(isset($_GET['p']) && $_GET['p']=='Kontakt'){
include ("pages/Kontakt.inc.php");
}
$događaj=(isset($_GET['događaj'])) ? $_GET['događaj'] : "none";
$mjesto=(isset($_GET['mjesto'])) ? $_GET['mjesto'] : "none";
$ponude=(isset($_GET['ponuda'])) ? $_GET['ponuda'] : "none"; elseif($ponude != "none"){ 
include ('pages/ponuda-template.inc.php');
} elseif($mjesto != "none"){
include ('pages/mjesta-template.inc.php');
} else $page = (isset($_GET['p'])) ? $_GET['p'] : "Početna";
include ('pages/pocetna.inc.php');
```

Comment: are these separate rules or you expect the same regular expressions hit twice?

Comment: hm sorry for my bad eng. well donow what u mean :) i am newbie. i have index.php?places=SiteName ,index.php?p=SiteName, index.php?pproducts=SiteName only ?p= works other not

Comment: i get for my ?p=siteneme like /sitename but for ?places=sitename,?products=sitename get /siteneme but nothing showing

Comment: It's not clear from this what your question is. What behavior do you expect?

Comment: You're not providing enough information about the structure of your site (although it is good you've provided the code). On my answer I'm guessing that you have a folder called "places."

Comment: my index?p=sitename give result /sitename and is ok but i want that  index?places=sitename, index?products=sitename, give me same. It give me same /sitename but dont redirect to index?places=sitename for examle i got emptie page

Comment: RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?p=$1    gives /sitename or 1d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?p=$1   gives /sitename or 1d   RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?shop=$1    gives /sitename or 1d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?shop=$1   gives /sitename or 1d                                                                      but only works for index.php?p=sitename not for index.php?shop=sitename

Answer (score 1):

The [`RewriteRules`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) you're using are too similar, meaning they will all return the same result.

If you have a directory called "places" at the `root` level, then you would do something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^places/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?places=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Note*: The rules are applied in the order they're reached (unlike conditions).

If you want to collect the same info to use for multiple query statements, then you would do something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?p=$1&places=$1 [L]
```

For `?p=sitename` for the sitename for the site you're handling requests for, you could use:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?p=%{HTTP_HOST}&places=$1 [L]
```

If you're trying to match a sitename that contains periods as a subdirectory:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-.]+)/?$ index.php?places=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1
```

Comment: i know this but i havnt dir places that is another query like         ?p=sitename, ?places=sitename or ?products=sitename that make me mad lol

Comment: They match patterns in those instances where there are no directories. Do you have different patterns you can elaborate on in the question?

Comment: here a part of my index.php    if(isset($_GET['p']) && $_GET['p']=='Kontakt'){
  include ("pages/Kontakt.inc.php");
  }
$događaj=(isset($_GET['događaj'])) ? $_GET['događaj'] : "none"; 
$mjesto=(isset($_GET['mjesto'])) ? $_GET['mjesto'] : "none";
$ponude=(isset($_GET['ponuda'])) ? $_GET['ponuda'] : "none"; 
elseif($ponude != "none"){
include ('pages/ponuda-template.inc.php');
 }
elseif($mjesto != "none"){
include ('pages/mjesta-template.inc.php');
 }
 else
$page = (isset($_GET['p'])) ? $_GET['p'] : "Početna";
    
include ('pages/pocetna.inc.php');